# AttributeError: 'module' object (scipy) has no attribute *** Why does this error occur?

Tags: python, scipy

In scipy, the error occurs quite often.

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.integrate.trapz(gyroSeries, timeSeries)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'integrate'
>>>
```

**I figure out how to solve this problem by doing the following:**

```
>>> 
>>> import scipy.integrate
>>> scipy.integrate.trapz(gyroSeries, timeSeries)
>>> 1.2
```

**My question:**

Why does the error occur?

Why would that fix the error?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most possibly because scipy is a library (package) that contains modules and to import a specific module from the scipy library, you need to specify it and import the module itself.  As it's a separate module (sub-package), once you import it, it's attributes are available to you by using the regular scipy.module.attribute

Answer (score 5):

In order to fix the error, add the following line at the top of your script

```
from scipy import integrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use

```
import scipy.constants as spc
```

and then

```
C   = spc.c #speed of light m/s
pi  = spc.pi
```